# Prevent RFI attacks when using URL variables

Tags: php, security, dynamic, error-handling

How can I check, if an URL variable is not valid or not? Like if I enter an invalid URL on my website: "`../index.php?page=skillsa`". For this, I get an error:

> Warning: include_once(views/skillsa.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tut01/index.php on line 22

How can I handle this type of error in the following code?

```
<?php
//error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//class for variables
include_once "classes/Page_Data.php";
$pageData = new Page_Data();

//
$pageData->title = "Portfolio site";
$pageData->content = include_once "views/navigation.php";
$pageData->css = "<link href='css/layout.css' rel='stylesheet'/>";

//url variables
$navigationIsClicked = isset($_GET['page']);
if($navigationIsClicked) {
    $fileToLoad = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $fileToLoad = "home";
}
$pageData->content .= include_once "views/$fileToLoad.php";

//embedded style
$pageData->embeddedStyle = "
<style>
    nav a[href *= '?page=$fileToLoad'] {
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>";

$page = include_once "templates/page.php";

echo $page;
```

**EDIT:**
Or can I just use an array to store all of the URL variables?

**Updated code:**

```
<?php
//error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$page_files=array( 'home', 'skills', 'projects', '404');

//class for variables
include_once "classes/Page_Data.php";
$pageData = new Page_Data();

//
$pageData->title = "Portfolio site";
$pageData->content = include_once "views/navigation.php";
$pageData->css = "<link href='css/layout.css' rel='stylesheet'/>";

//url variables
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if (in_array($_GET['page'], $page_files)) {
        $fileToLoad = $_GET['page'];
    } else {
        $fileToLoad = '404';
    }
} else {
    $fileToLoad = 'home';
}

$pageData->content .= include_once "views/$fileToLoad.php";

//embedded style
$pageData->embeddedStyle = "
<style>
    nav a[href *= '?page=$fileToLoad'] {
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>";

$page = include_once "templates/page.php";

echo $page;
```

Comment: Well it probably works with `../../../etc/passwd\0` though. If that's not what you want consider `basename` normalization and regex-constraints, and a `file_exists` check.

Comment: @mario yes, I want eliminate all exploit possibilities and errors.

Comment: I would use file_exists(), and path_info() or basename() on the filename.  Only put the filename in, and use a hard coded root path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want but this is what I think you want.

```
 //url variables
 if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if (in_array($_GET['page'], $page_files)) {
          //basename returns only the filename part of a path ~ might have to check this
          // when using just text such as "somepage", it's used for things like "../../somepage" 
          // and returns just "somepage"
          $fileToLoad = "views/".basename( $_GET['page'] ) .".php";
          //echo $fileToLoad;
          if(!file_exists( $fileToLoad ) ){
               $fileToLoad = "views/404.php";
          }
     } else {
         $fileToLoad = "views/404.php";
     }
 } else {
     $fileToLoad = "views/home.php";
 }


 $pageData->content .= include_once $fileToLoad;
```

Comment: Something like that. Tell me is this a good way to prevent Remote File Inclusion attacks(store url variables in array)?

Comment: the only file they can include has to be in "views" if you use basename( )